# should i create .parquet file in the directory path in order to write data frame in parquet format?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hadoop, parquet

I'm trying to write parquet data but when I run this code I do not see any parquet file created in the specified write path. should I create an empty folder and point to write to that folder or create a .parquet file and overwrite the data to the already created parquet file?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object csv_parquet {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Csv_To_Parquet").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
         .option("delimiter",",")
         .option("header", "true")
         .option("path", "C:\\Users\\kiran\\Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv").load()
df.show()
df.write
  .parquet("C:\\parquet_data")
spark.read.parquet("C:\\parquet_data").show()
spark.close()
}
}
```

Comment: This should work if you don't see any errors.  So, any errors?

Comment: The DataFrame writer always makes directories, not files. I highly doubt Spark can write directly to your C drive root

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, all I see as my output is csv data but parquet file is not created at the location that I've specified (that's the reason no parquet data is read). the path that I have specified is empty.

Comment: @kanielc all i did is to create an empty folder parquet_data in my c drive and pass it as the path to write the parquet data. but I don't see any file created its still empty but the csv data frame is generated as my output.

Comment: If the directory already exists that should be an issue.  Try this: `df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("C:\\parquet_data")` and let me know.